# ENOENT on writeFileSync works on repl fails on gulp-asset-manifest

Tags: node.js, gulp

I'm using the code on [this site](http://blog.icanmakethiswork.io/2014/11/using-gulp-in-visual-studio-instead-of-web-optimization.html) to write a gulp file for a Windows aspnet + angularjs app.

I'm running only styles for now, and when I run gulp I get:

```
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'C:\project\build\manifest-debug.json'
at Error (native)
at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:502:18)
at Object.fs.writeFileSync (fs.js:1103:15)
at writeManifestFile (C:\project\node_modules\gulp-asset-manifest\index.js:30:8)
at resetManifestFile (C:\project\node_modules\gulp-asset-manifest\index.js:51:5)
at module.exports (C:\project\node_modules\gulp-asset-manifest\index.js:76:5)
at getManifest (C:\project\Gulpfile.js:97:12)
at Gulp.<anonymous> (C:\project\Gulpfile.js:126:15)
at module.exports (C:\project\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:34:7)
at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (C:\project\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:273:3)
```

Looking at `C:\project\node_modules\gulp-asset-manifest\index.js:30:8` I see:

```
fs.writeFileSync(filename, JSON.stringify(data));
```

So I ran this on node's REPL:

```
fs.writeFileSync('C:\\project\\build\\manifest-debug.json', 'hi');
```

And the file was created correctly.

I tried running gulp again with an existing file and got the exact same error.

I added a `console.log(filename);` before line 30 on index.js and I got:

```
./build/manifest-debug.json
```

So I ran `fs.writeFileSync('./build/manifest-debug.json', 'hi');` on REPL from the same folder and it worked too.

Not sure what's going on.

I'm running everything with UAC disabled and on a command prompt with admin rights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was fs.writeFileSync requires the path to exist.

At the point `gulp-asset-manifest` was called `./build` was nonexistent, because the `clean` task deleted the entire path.